# Difference between 位于, 处在, 地处 and 处于？

Tags: difference

They are the same, they all mean “be located in (at)...”
Is there any difference between 位于, 处在, 地处 and 处于? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

位于 = located at (refers to the location of people, objects, or places)

地处: geographically located at. e.g. 'XX鎮地处華北' (XX Town is geographically located in northern China)

处于 = at/ in [mostly refers to a situation or status.  e.g. 处于緊張狀態 (in a tense stage)]

*处在 is an uncommon variant (almost no one use it) of 处于*

Comment: why in this sentence is 处在? when you use it？why not "处于"?                                      
   北京处在华北平原。

Comment: Either 北京位于华北平原 or 北京地处华北平原 would sound better than 北京处在华北平原. '位於' and '地处' are common compound words. 处在 is made up of two single-character words 处(locate) and 在(at). Although grammatically valid, it sounds very awkward

Comment: When you mean 位于, don't replace it with 处在; When you mean 处于, don't replace it with 处在. In short-- don't use 处在. While I am at it... when you mean 身处 [(personally located) at; in ], don't replace it with 处在 neither

Comment: Very good interpretations.